# Why do my JSONP requests occasionally fail?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp

I'm getting this error from time to time, normally when I first run my app:

`Uncaught TypeError: Property 'jQuery182034483651514165103_1353334474761' of object [object Window] is not a function`

Then I refresh and it works fine. I've actually got this on other apps I've built too, and astonishingly google produces no similar issues. The thing that makes this unique is the callback name - I'm not using a custom callback function name or function - it's just the standard `$.ajax()` with `dataType: 'jsonp'`

Any idea how this could happen?

Comment: Have you tried setting the callback function name yourself to see how it behaves? That callback function name is hellaciously long, although that may not be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this was caused by the face that I had a timeout of 10000 (10 seconds). When the response took longer than 10 seconds, jQuery deleted the callback function referenced in my question. So when the response finally did come back, it tried to execute the deleted function. So I increased the timeout to 15 seconds and so far so good.